# Ternary return type inferred from parameter failure (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, type-inference, ternary

After a long time reading questions and looking at the docs I still need help.
My problem is quite simple. I want to define a function that returns an array when an array is given as parameter but Typescript never let me return the wanted value.

I simplified the function i want to code here as the error is still the same.

```
function notWorkingTernary(val: number | number[]) : typeof val extends number[] ? string[] : string{
  if(Array.isArray(val)){
    return val.map(v=>String(v));
  }
  else{
    return String(val);
  }
}
```

This function is getting the following error at the first return (line 3) :
`Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)`

I don't understand why would Typescript want me to return  a string type even when the type of val is clearly an array of number here.

If I avoid giving a return type then the return type is always string | string[] and I have to cast the return type myself each time i use the function.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: FYI, what you are calling "ternary types" are known as "[conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types)".  You'll have a better time searching for answers/docs/issues if you use that terminology instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [function signature overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads). In your case it should look like this:

```js
function notWorkingTernary(val: number): string;
function notWorkingTernary(val: number[]): string[];

function notWorkingTernary(val: number | number[]): (string | string[]) {
  if(Array.isArray(val)){
    return val.map(v=>String(v));
  }
  else{
    return String(val);
  }
}
```

Basically, you've got one function with several "type overloads" which are handled in runtime and by declaring types you promise that runtime is compatible with typings.

[Typescript playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABGOUDqcBOBrGYDmAKgKaZgCGmAngBQBu5ANgFzIgC2ARqQJSsDOUTHnwBuALAAoUJFgJkqDDhEkylWgxZsupANoBdPokHCCBiZKkzo8JCnRZcBVRWr0mrMB26ZEAH20fAyMaExF-YyERYMQAbylERBhgGgBBTExyKgA6GH50zI0mHh54yUTEzGIoEDJETWz2cgAHegBeAD4AZSiCehKLRIBfBMRiRn5iMorEKpq6ntN8d0YeQcQRyU2pCARBRAAPRDaFB2VnUldaXQBGABpEAGYHgBZDC12wfapj06UnIiXdQ0G5rKRAA)

Answer (score 1):

```
function notWorkingTernary<T extends number | number[]>(val: T): T extends number[] ? string[] : string{
  if(Array.isArray(val)){
    return val.map(v=>String(v)) as T extends number[] ? string[] : string;
  }
  else{
    return String(val) as T extends number[] ? string[] : string;
  }
}
```

maybe someone knows a smart way to get rid of `as T extends number[] ? string[] : string`?

Comment: You can get rid of it with overloads, but it's not any better to do that in my opinion.  Neither method is type safe; this is an open issue... see [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912)